# How to test window scroll event with vue-testing-library?

Tags: vue.js, tdd

I want to trigger user interaction for window scroll to change the isScrolled data so that the div class can change. Right now I just test the component when the isScrolled data is changed. Is this the right way to test?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is acceptable way to test. However, instead of directly setting the `isScrolled` to `true`, call the method using the `vm` as (ensure that you have mocked the `document.documentElement.topScroll` to something other than zero):

```
wrapper.vm.onScrollHandler();
```

Finally, if you need to really test for scroll event, you can manually fire one using the `dispatchEvent()` method as following:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('scroll', { detail: 'anything' }));
```

You use this and then run your assertion.

On a side note, instead of pictures of your code, paste actual snippets so that they are easy to copy and paste. And, you `onScrollHandler` can be shortened to:

```
onScrollHandler() {
  this.isScrolled = document.documentElement.topScroll > 0;
}
```